# I have warnings in my console with my amp story

Tags: amp-html

I create an amp story. I use amp animations. When I play the story, I get warnings in the console for every animation type "pan".

```
<amp-img src="assets/images/paulrudd_wikimedia.webp"
    animate-in="pan-left"
    animate-in-duration="9s"
    alt="Le Temple d&#39;Or"
    attribution="Kit Suman/Unsplash"
    width="1280"
    height="1280"
    layout="fixed">
    <amp-img src="assets/images/paulrudd_wikimedia.jpg"
      fallback
      animate-in="pan-left"
      animate-in-duration="9s"
      alt="Le Temple d&#39;Or"
      attribution="Kit Suman/Unsplash"
      width="1280"
      height="1280"
      layout="fixed"></amp-img>
</amp-img>
```

Here is the warning when **pan-left**:
`Invalid keyframe value for property transform: translate(NaNpx, NaNpx) scale(Infinity) native-web-animation-runner.js:85 
Invalid keyframe value for property transform: translate(0px, NaNpx) scale(Infinity) native-web-animation-runner.js:85`

and when **pan-down**:
`Invalid keyframe value for property transform: translate(NaNpx, 0px) scale(Infinity) native-web-animation-runner.js:85
Invalid keyframe value for property transform: translate(NaNpx, NaNpx) scale(Infinity) native-web-animation-runner.js:85`

I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error its not related to the AMP implementation at all.The web-animation-runner.js belongs to the Web Animation API, not to AMP. Try adding the -webkit-animation css property with some value to your image. (Can't propose a value since I have no idea what are you trying to achieve)..and please, next time, a jsfiddle with full code.